# Error alternating between Unable to compile class for JSP & Unable to load class for JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat7

I am working on a web application written mainly in jsp by someone before me. Everything was working fine well, but suddenly when I try to run the project on server (from Eclipse), I am getting the following two error in the browser and eclipse:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:84)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:409)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:288)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:267)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:293)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

When I refresh the browser, I get a different error.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to load class for JSP

type Exception report

message Unable to load class for JSP

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:598)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:137)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:305)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.automation.actions.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:133)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:65)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:596)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:137)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:305)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I read in many places that the error is due to tomcat not pointed to the right jdk, which I've done. It is pointing to Java 1.7. If I point to 1.8, I get `The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` error.

The code was working fine the earlier, and I am not sure what exactly happened. I've got this error in the past as well, and I used to re import the project etc to resolve it. This time I would really like to get to the root of it since this seem to happen once in a while. I am sure it is some configuration which I am missing but I am not sure what.

Comment: can somebody explain why they are downvoting please?

Answer (score 0):

First check your this page for Tomcat VS Java versions compatibility : http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

If you're using tomcat 8.x or 7.x Java 7 or 8 are OK. Choose JDK8 if you can.

Next, if you want to avoid this kind of problems configure and recompile your eclipse project to with the same jdk (check you build settings).